# Selenium Python - How to manage to get past cookie consent window

Tags: python, selenium, cookies

I had a working code for a picture scraper. But it stopped working.
Tried different solutions I found, but I just don't seem to be able to tell Selenium to accept the cookie consent it redirects to.
Any help much appreciated

```
wd = webdriver.Chrome('D://chromedriver.exe')
wd.execute_script('''window.open("about:blank");''')  
wd.switch_to.window(wd.window_handles[1]) 
wd.get("https://google.com")
wd.implicitly_wait(10)
search_url = "https://www.google.com/search?safe=off&site=&tbm=isch&source=hp&q={q}&oq={q}&gs_l=img"
#wd.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="uc-btn-accept-banner"]').click()
wd.implicitly_wait(3)
wd.get(search_url.format(q='Volkswagen'))
WebDriverWait(wd,10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe[src^='https://consent.google.com']")))
WebDriverWait(wd,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//div[@id='introAgreeButton']"))).click()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is against the Google policy.
Even if you get around the cookie consent, Most likely you'll be blocked from google for asking too much data.

Comment: I will ask for about 100 images within 30 minutes. Just don't want to save by mouse and click - didn't and won't get blocked for something so lightweight I hope

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
WebDriverWait(wd,10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe[src^='https://consent.google.com']")))
WebDriverWait(wd,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//div[@id='introAgreeButton']"))).click()
```

To:

```
WebDriverWait(wd, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[contains(text(), 'Accept all')]")))
wd.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//*[contains(text(), 'Accept all')]")[1].click()
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use google search api. It is free within a certain limit, it will be enough for you.

```
https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/introduction
```